# What are breakable non-whitespace characters

Tags: html, css, browser, unicode, line-breaks

I found out that browsers (I tested only Chrome behaviour) breaks line on some characters in words to prevent text overflow (in standard behaviour, thus: `word-wrap: normal`). I don't think about breakable whitespace, but about these concrete Unicode characters:

- hyphen(-)
- soft hyphen (­)
- dash (–)
- long dash (—)
- full-width plus/minus (＋/－)
- minus (−)

So the questions...

- Is there any other character with this property?
- Why exactly these characters and not any other punctation characters (like dot, comma or slash)?
- I know why hyphens and dash, but why plus and minus and not for example multiply (×)??
- Is this behaviour consistent across browsers? Standardized in HTML/CSS or Unicode?

Have a [try](https://jsfiddle.net/utp0q2z1/):

```
<div style="width: 50px">
veryvery-veryvery-veryvery-veryvery
veryvery–veryvery–veryvery–veryvery
veryvery—veryvery—veryvery—veryvery
veryvery­veryvery­veryvery­veryvery
veryvery−veryvery−veryvery−veryvery
veryvery＋veryvery＋veryvery＋veryvery
long
</div>
```

Comment: Why not dot or comma? I suppose they had to reach a compromise. I only know Spanish and English and you cannot split text at those characters (`One<LF>, two`). And splitting at long dash is definitively wrong in Spanish and leads to broken ebooks all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaks in HTML/CSS text generally occur at "[soft wrap opportunities](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#soft-wrap-opportunity)", but the specific behaviour around which characters present such an opportunity is not standardised. Rather, the CSS specification defers to other text formatting specifications (e.g. language-specific guidelines).

However, a popular generic implementation is the [Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/). The algorithm examines the Unicode properties of neighbouring characters with a set of rules to either create, force, or inhibit break points. It is not possible to come up with a complete list of individual characters that can create a break because the context that the character appears in is a relevant factor.

Comment: Thanks, Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm is really good reference.